# a Cisco router with multiple DHCP servers and one Cisco layer 3 switch

Tags: server, layer, cisco, dhcp, vlan

I have a small business router Cisco rv134w, I have three VLAN and DHCP server on it and each VLAN on a physical port also I have a cisco layer 3 switches which I want to separate it to three zones for each VLANs, I already try by creating vlan2,3,4 on cisco switch and give them IP address also I was using IP helper-address by I have conflicting IP address.
Does any solution, please?

Comment: Please post your DHCP and VLAN config.

Comment: Best and standard solution is : configure IP-Helper address for each Interface Vlan.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mask to seperate your ip subnets 
For example if your ip address is 192.168.1.0/24
Your first vlan should have the address in the range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.30
Second vlan: 192.168.1.33-192.168.1.62
Third vlan :192.168.1.65-192.168.1.94

If you still have problems give me an ip address similare to yours and i will calculate for you